# What happen when the activity crash?

Tags: android, android-service, ipc, android-service-binding, bindservice

I have a service created like this :

```
<service
    android:name="com.myFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Then I implement the `onBind` like this:

```
  private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
  private myListener mListener;


  public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LocalService getService() {
      return LocalService.this;
    }
  }

  public void setListener(myListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
  }    

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
  } 

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (mListener != null) mListener.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);  
  }
```

It is quite simple: the Activity binds to the Service and sets up a listener. When the Service receives a message it simply fires the listener

Now the big question: **what happen if the activity crash suddenly?**  In that case `mListener` will point to something non-existent, no?

How, before calling `mListener.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)`, can I check to see if the bound Activity is still alive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) and [DeadObjectException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html) since your `Activity` seems to be in another app. This will allow you to know if the `Activity` was garbage collected because your reference will become `null` and you will not leak.

```
private WeakReference<MyListener> mListener;
```

This is how you store the `WeakReference`.

```
public void setListener(MyListener listener) 
{
   mListener = new WeakReference<MyListener>(listener);
}
```

This is how you use it.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
{
    MyListener listener = mListener.get();

    if(listener != null)
    {
        try
        {
            listener.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);  
        }
        catch(DeadObjectException exception)
        {

        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Activity was destroyed.
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm what if the app crash between  MyListener listener = mListener.get(); and listener.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage); ? also as i understand weakreference are deleted when the GC ran, and this is not necessarily at the time the app crash no ?

Comment: Once you have the `listener` reference then it cannot be GC. If the app crashes then all will get GC, but yes `WeakReference` are deleted on GC.

Comment: yes but is useless to have reference to it if the app is crashed because most probably the code inside listener will crash also of behave unexpected ...

Comment: @john since your `Activity` seems to be in another app you can use the `DeadObjectException` to know when the `Activity` is dead. I updated the answer above.